# Wordpress: Add a field to the wordpress posts table

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm working on a web app whereby I need to add extra info to the wordpress posts database but wordpress posts table does not have the extra columns.

So I inserted my own fields; **favicon, image, domain** which store urls for an article since I'm havesting the articles from a JSON feed.

However when I try to insert a post into the database, the post is inserted but my extra columns are left blank while the default fields are populated.

Here is how I inserted into the database

```
<?php

require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../wp-config.php");

$json_feed = "http://digitalrand.net/api/url_data/?key=xxxxxx&pass=xxxxxxx%";
$json = file_get_contents($json_feed);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($obj as $article_array){
    $url = $article_array['url'];
    $domain = $article_array['domain'];
    $favicon = $article_array['favicon'];
    $title = $article_array['title'];
    $category = $article_array['category'];
    $large_summary = $article_array['summary'];
    $sum = implode(',',$large_summary);
    $images = $article_array['images'];
    $i = reset($images);

    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $sum,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_category' => $category,
        'post_template' => 'content.php'
        );

    wp_insert_post ($post, $wp_error);

           $post_id = $wpdb -> insert_id;  

    $extra = array('post_image', 'post_favicon', 'post_domain');
    $data = array($image, $favicon, $domain);

    add_post_meta($post_id, $extra, $data, true);
 ?>
```

How would I be able to populate my extra columns as I insert a post

This is the error log I get from Apache:

```
 PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php on line 880
 PHP Stack trace:
 PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-content\\themes\\twentyfourteen\\data.php:0
 PHP   2. add_post_meta() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-content\\themes\\twentyfourteen\\data.php:42
 PHP   3. add_metadata() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\post.php:1731
 PHP   4. wpdb->insert() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\meta.php:68
 PHP   5. wpdb->_insert_replace_helper() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php:1275
 PHP   6. wpdb->prepare() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php:1336
 PHP   7. array_walk() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php:1005
 PHP   8. wpdb->escape_by_ref() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php:1005
 PHP   9. wpdb->_real_escape() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php:952
 PHP  10. mysql_real_escape_string() C:\\wamp\\www\\abacus\\wp-includes\\wp-db.php:880
```

What am I doing wrong since the posts are being inserted but the post_meta is not being inserted into the database.?

I've added the following in the **content.php** file of my main theme where all the posts are displayed.

```
 <?php
     $post_Id = get_the_ID();
     $favicon_values = get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_favicon', true);
     echo $favicon_values;
 ?>
```

Is this how I'm supposed to display favicon_values for each article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert favicon, domain & others fields in wp_postmeta table, its a better practice than change structure of wp_posts table.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
//now you can use $post_id withing add_post_meta or update_post_meta
<?php add_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_favicon', $favicon, true ) || update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_favicon', $favicon ); ?>
```

Your code should like this.

Comment: I removed the image, favicon and domain from the $post array...check edit.

Comment: Having added the post_meta field data to an array: extra and the data I want to insert into an array: $data. I've checked on the wordpress codex and the add_post_meta if used in the way u've defined, Adds a new custom field if the key does not already exist, or updates the value of the custom field with that key otherwise. So I figure I don't have to create the fields in the posts_meta table from phpmyadmin right?

Comment: And how would I display the new post_meta data to the content page?

Comment: when you show content from wp_posts then you'll get post_id, by post id & meta_key you can easlity find the data.example:

 <?php echo  $favicon_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_favicon',true ); ?>

Comment: Check my edit on how i'm trying to display the post_meta content

Comment: And what is your problem now?

Comment: After all the edits I've made to my code which are all displayed above. Nothing is getting inserted into the database but I've inspected the array i'm fetching from the JSON feed and it has content.

Comment: When I echo the $post_id, I get **00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**

Comment: use $post_id =wp_insert_post ($post, $wp_error); instead,

then echo $post_id;

Comment: I still get the same result **00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**

Comment: I checked the error logs and turns out that I had not removed the image, domain and favicon fields from the posts table. I have removed them and when I echoed the post_id variable I got 29748 which is ok but I also get an error ** mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\abacus\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 880**

Comment: My Posts are being inserted but however the posts meta is not being inserted

Comment: try same as,  add_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_favicon', $favicon, true ) || update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_favicon', $favicon ); 

make sure do place this code after immediate wp_post_insert with $post_id;

Comment: Yeah it has worked. But is there a way I can insert an array of post meta for domain, favicon and image instead of only the favicon field?

Comment: then you have to maintain one meta_key like 'favicon_domain_image' & meta_value would be serialize data or you can concate with a delimeter using implode.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you would do it e.g. inserting favicon and domain to the posts meta. I'm kinda new into php programming especially working with wordpress